# how to merge multiple rows in a single row by oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

my data be like :

```
ROW    DATA
1       OK
1       OK
2       ERROR
2       ERROR
```

I want merge data group by row

```
ROW     DATA
1       OK,OK
2       ERROR,ERROR
```

WHICH function could work out ?

Comment: Are you using a programming language?

Comment: i am writing a sql query

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use LISTAGG to query the same:

```
select ROW_, 
       listagg(DATA_, ',') within group (order by ROW_) as DATAS 
from MYTBL
group by ROW_
```

Test query in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28fe19/1)

Answer (score 0):

For oracle versions older then 11g Release 2 you can use WMSYS package, function WM_CONCAT()

```
Select ROW_, 
       WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(DATA_)  
From MYTBL
Group By ROW_
```

Comment: [Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier